# How does Variable > -1 exactly evaluate in C?

Tags: c, casting, twos-complement

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main()
{
    uint16_t peter = 8;
    uint32_t peter2 = 8;
    if(peter > -1)
    {
        printf("Peter true\n"); //expected
    } 
    if (peter2 > -1)
    {
        printf("Peter 2 true\n"); //wtf, why not
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Why does the first statement enter the clause and the second does not (on a 32bit architecture)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules <- Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned integer type. (about the second one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation for the difference between `peter > -1` and `peter2 > -1` are the notions of “integer promotion”, and also “usual arithmetic conversions”.

“[Integer promotion](https://cigix.me/c17#6.3.1.1.p2)” means that any integer type `t` narrower than `int` is “promoted” to either `int` (if `int` can contain all the values of `t`) or `unsigned int` otherwise. In your example and with your compiler, promotion is applied to `peter`, which is converted to `int` before being compared to `-1` (which also has type `int`).

Then, the “[usual arithmetic conversions](https://cigix.me/c17#6.3.1.8)” decide what happen when an arithmetic binary operation, here `>`, is applied to operands of different types. Between an unsigned and a signed integer type of the same width, these rules say that the signed operand is converted to unsigned before the operation takes place.

`-1` has type `int`. When it is compared to `peter2`, the usual arithmetic conversions mean `-1` is converted to `uint32_t`, becoming a large value (greater than `8`).

Comment: Because int has size if int32_t, right?

Comment: @Niclas Yes. Answering the question precisely without saying anything that can technically be wrong is made a bit difficult by the use of `uint32_t` in the question, which with the information provided (“a 32-bit architecture”) could be an alias for `unsigned`, an alias for `unsigned long`, or a 32-bit wide unsigned integer type distinct from these two. So I didn't go into the details. The good news is that the rules are designed so that you get the same result for the program in the question regardless of such details, but it is possible to observe the difference with `_Generic`.

Answer (score 1):

It's all to do with [implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion).

For `peter > -1` the value of `peter` is *promoted* to an `int`. But for `peter2 > -1` it's the value of `-1` which is *converted* to an `uint32_t`.

And in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) systems `-1` is all ones, so is converted to the value `2147483647`, which is quite a bit larger than the value `8` of `peter2`, making the condition false.

Comment: The conversion from signed to unsigned is agnostic of the bit representation. https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p2 - "*...if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.*" It's just that in two's complement it is done "naturally", without extra steps.